# ReactJS with Webpack Setup - App Shows A Blank Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

[image]I had a different thread here: [React Build Tool and Dev Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979547/react-build-tool-and-dev-server)
to setup React with Webpack. Seems like it is working but I have an issue with having the html page show the code from entry point app.js . I can see the code is in bundle.js. If I modify anything in app.js till the render method e.g enter a typo or something I see an error on console but nothing happens with the render() method. Not matter what I do there is no error and nothing shows but a blank page.

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      ReactDOM.render(<h1>Render me!</h1>, 
        document.getElementById('app'))
    );
  }
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <!-- Bootstrap, latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src='bundle.js'></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

So if I view page source it just shows just 
and not the expected

## Render me!

And just in case below is my webpack.config

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './src/app.js'
  },

   output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
   resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

Also this is from my package.json. I believe my bundle.js is being served from memory right now.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --hot --inline",
    "build": "webpack --progress --colors"
  }
```

I run npm start to compile and start the server. I was expecting npm build will build to dist folder but it doesn't . For now I just want this working one way or the other so I can start coding.

And .babelrc

```
{
   "presets":[
        "es2017", "react"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you try placing the `<script type="text/javascript" src='bundle.js'></script>` in `index.html` below the `body` tag?

Comment: ok I did that but still the same result

Comment: When you say "no error", do you have the developer tools open to the console?

Comment: Correct, on chrome dev tools' console no error is generated if  I mess up the syntax within Render but anything before that it shows an error.

Comment: What are you using from stage-1?

Comment: Someone had that in their file I copied. I got rid of that now. So don't think that is the issue

Comment: Do I understand correctly that a `dist` directory and `bundles.js`file are not generated at all?

Comment: Get rid of all that  `class App extends React.Component` code within the first block of your question. It should just be `ReactDOM.render(<h1>Render me!</h1>, 
        document.getElementById('app'))`.

Comment: If for some reason your DOM isn't available by the time react is trying to execute, you can enclose the render code in a [`DOMContentLoaded` callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Comment: Best practice is to give webpack `entry` a [`context`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/)

Comment: I'd consider moving your babel config into a separate [.babelrc file](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/) to keep webpack cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: I don't know what you're importing into your js files, but i'm pretty sure you don't need to resolve `*`, I haven't even seen that before.

Comment: Which js file are you referring to? I have only one file yet app.js with imports for React and ReacDOM

Comment: 1) What's the result when you made the other changes I suggested? 2) Also you didn't respond to _Do I understand correctly that a `dist` directory and `bundles.js`file are not generated at all?_ 3) You have to @ me if you want me to get notified. *You aren't making it easy to help.

Comment: @1252748 Sorry I'll include your name with @ now. Here are answers to your questions
1- Well that solved the issue, you are a genius! Did not need the class App extends React.Component. Will you mind describing what happened here and why no error was generated?
2- Correct, dist and bundle.js is not generated on the file system but I can view code in bundle.js. I read here somewhere that probably it is being served from memory which I'm ok for now during development.
3- Guess I won't have to because you solved the issue haha...Thanks again!

Comment: So help provided by @1252748 fixed the issue:
Only needed: ReactDOM.render(<h1>Render me!</h1>, 
        document.getElementById('app')) and not the code related to class.

Answer (score 0):

You are using WebPack 3.x?
Try this config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const PreloadWebpackPlugin = require('preload-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const staticSourcePath = path.join(__dirname, 'static');
const sourcePath = path.join(__dirname);
const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
          devServer: {    
          historyApiFallback: true,
          contentBase: './'
      },
    entry: {
        "index" :path.resolve(sourcePath, 'index.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.webpack-loader.js', '.web-loader.js', '.loader.js', '.js', '.jsx'],
        modules: [
            sourcePath,
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            filename: 'vendor.[chunkhash].js',
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
                postcss: [
                    autoprefixer({
                        browsers: [
                            'last 3 version',
                            'ie >= 10'
                        ]
                    })
                ],
                context: staticSourcePath
            }
        }),
        new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            path: buildPath,
            excludeChunks: ['base'],
            filename: 'index.html',
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                collapseInlineTagWhitespace: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true
            }
        }),
        new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
            rel: 'preload',
            as: 'script',
            include: 'all',
            fileBlacklist: [/\.(css|map)$/, /base?.+/]
        }),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()

    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                  options: {
                    presets: ['env', 'react'],
                  }
                },
                include: sourcePath
            },
            {                
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: true } },
                        'postcss-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot?.+|svg?.+|ttf?.+|otf?.+|woff?.+|woff2?.+)$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    'url-loader?limit=20480&name=assets/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
                ],
                include: staticSourcePath
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes I am using webpack 3.0  but I really don't have to. I went ahead and gave this a try and had to install bunch of packages and and still cannot get it to to build. Seems like if I use that I need bunch of other things. There has to be a simple config file I can use to get this working.

Comment: Yeah, some plugins are redundant, but this worked for me also with old IE8. If you don't receive any errors from compile process, so the problem could be elsewhere